# spacing after a certain string (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, spacing

I want to space after certain string. for example:

```
string str = "DASEULE"
```

Now, I want to add a *space* after `"DAS"` and it will write to UI Text as `"DAS EULE"`. How can i do this?
Thanks

Edit: the all chars are uppercase. Sorry

Comment: I have a feeling I read your question wrong after leaving an answer. You want to add space if the there is capital letter in the string?

Comment: Actually the all chars are uppercase. there are artikels. "Das","Die","Der" etc. I solved myself but I think it is not stable. I'll try another solving, maybe the following answers

Comment: *"Actually. The all chars are uppercase. it has "DASEULE" instead of "DasEule""* Please fix your question. The example you used is a bit confusing. Check ren's answer. That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: fixed. Sorry again, it was my fault

Comment: No problem. The big question is how do we know when to add space since there other different keywords like DIE and DER...... Do you have list of all these words that requires space after them?

Comment: I wrote this code: switch (wordPanel.GetChild(0).GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text)
            {
                case "DAS":
                    text.text = spacing.Replace("DAS", "DAS ");
                    break;
                default:
                    text.text = spacing;
                    break;
            } How is this? according to you, can be?

Comment: As long as all input is all uppercase there is no way to suggest a generic approach, you couldn't differenciate between two separate words `THECAT` should be `THE CAT` and correct one words like  `THERMAL` or `THEORY`.

Comment: you're right. but I have no other choice. anyway, the artikels won't be in game. neverthless. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```cs
string s1 = "DasEule";
s1.Replace("Das", "Das ");
```

Or

```
string s2 = "DasEule";
s2.Insert(2, " ");
```

Comment: your code can be. it works but I don't know is this stable. because there are more artikels, not only "DAS"

Answer (score 0):

Not the best code in the world, check the problem mentioned in the question comments, but should work. Is a variant of Ren's answer.

```
private string AddSpacesIfNecessary(string word)
{
    string[] prefixes = new string[] { "DAS", "DIE", "DER" }; // Add other prefixes
    foreach(string prefix in prefixes)
    {
        if(word.StartsWith(prefix))
        {
            return word.Insert(prefix.Length - 1, " ");
        }
    }
    // Prefixes are not found, no need to add spaces
    return word;
}
```